# openVPN file transfer speed

Tags: networking, openvpn, samba

**Problem:**
File downloads to remote office, pulling data from server are stuck at 128KB/sec (as reported by windows explorer), which is roughly 1mbps.

**Question:** *Why can't I get close to remote office download speed, 750KB/sec or 6 mbps when pulling a file from server that has a 20 mbps internet connection?*

```
linux openVPN server 20/20 mbps internet connection (server location - EoC service)
    -same LAN as openVPN server is ubuntu RAID10 file server, SAMBA   
windows7 openVPN client 10/2 mbps internet connection (remote office - ADSL service)
```

iperf results:

```
TCP

    openVPN client box (remote office)
    iperf -s

    openVPN server box
    iperf -c <remoteOffice **public IP**>
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
    [  3]  0.0-10.3 sec  6.75 MBytes  5.48 Mbits/sec

    openVPN server box
    iperf -c <remoteOffice **openVPN IP**>
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
    [  3]  0.0-10.2 sec  7.12 MBytes  5.84 Mbits/sec

UDP

    openVPN client box (remote office)
    iperf -s -u

    openVPN server box
    iperf -c <remoteOffice **public IP**> -u -b 6M
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
    [  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  7.15 MBytes  6.01 Mbits/sec   0.307 ms    0/ 5102 (0%)
    [  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order

    penVPN server box
    iperf -c <remoteOffice **openVPN IP**> -u -b 6M
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
    [  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  7.15 MBytes  6.00 Mbits/sec   1.310 ms    0/ 5103 (0%)
```

data being uploaded from server location to remote office is sent at roughly the rates I would expect, i.e. being limited by the 10 mbps download connection at the remote office.

Both tests over the public interface AND openVPN adapter seemed similar. Why doesn't windows7 pull at the speeds shown above?

**Edit--as requested**

These results are really odd.....

iperf results the other way around:

```
TCP

    openVPN server box
    iperf -s

    openVPN client box (remote office)
    iperf -c <server **public IP**>
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
    [  3]  0.0-11.0 sec  2.00 MBytes  1.52 Mbits/sec

    openVPN client box (remote office)
    iperf -c <server **openVPN Server IP**>
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
    [  3]  0.0-10.3 sec  7.75 MBytes  6.34 Mbits/sec

UDP

    openVPN server box
    iperf -s -u

    openVPN client box (remote office)
    iperf -c <server **public IP**> -u -b 6M
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
    [  3]  0.0-12.1 sec  1.03 MBytes   711 Kbits/sec   7.327 ms 4367/ 5101 (86%)

    openVPN client box (remote office)
    iperf -c <server **openVPN IP**> -u -b 6M
    [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
    [  3]  0.0- 9.8 sec  7.15 MBytes  6.11 Mbits/sec   1.686 ms    0/ 5102 (0%)
    [  3]  0.0- 9.8 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order
```

**Edit - 8/10/2015**
I did some tests from a Windows7 box inside the LAN of a Windows Server 2008 file share; and the speed was 100MB/sec.

Same file transferred from an Ubuntu Server Samba share was 64MB/sec.

Same transfer speed differences across the openVPN connection. 
Windows Server 2008 Share - 1.4MB/sec.
Ubuntu Server Samba Share - 70KB/sec.

I looked into the problem Ubuntu Server Samba Socket Options and found

```
SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
```

I increased the send/receive buffers to

```
SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
```

Now the transfer speeds between Win. Server and Ubuntu Samba shares are similar. So, in the end it looks to be a mis-config of Samba, not openVPN that was causing the slow transfers.

Comment: What happens when you perform your Iperf tests the other way around?  Remember that iperf is not bidirectional by default.

Comment: edited post to include iperf, remoteOffice = client, openVpn Server = server

Comment: Well looking at your iperf results in the other direction you seem to be getting somewhere between 0.7-1.5MB/s of bandwidth. Which seems to match exactly the numbers you state in your first sentence. BTW your use of the term download in this question isn't very helpful. The direction of data flow wasn't entirely clear from your question.

Comment: iperf --client sends data, correct? I.e. would measure upload speed on the client's end?